# Under what conditions does $AEA^{-1}=E $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In matrix multiplication when does $AEA^{-1}=E $?

if any are the identity then it's trivial.

Extra question, are there non diagnol matrices solutions or a proof one can't exist?

Comment: Note that on such an occasion, the matrices commute, that is, $AE = EA$.

Comment: Plenty of non-diagonal  ones. For example let $A$ be any invertible matrix and  let $E=A$. Or let $E=A^k$.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is equivalent to the assertion that $A$ is invertible and $AE = EA$, the latter condition saying that they commute. One non-trivial example is to let $A$ be any rotation about some axis, and let $E$ be any stretch along that axis. Then they clearly satisfy the requirements. I don't know if there is any nice characterization of such pairs of matrices though.